# Requirements for creating livewallpaper for Android

Tags: android, andengine

So far I haven't seen a simple tutorial on creating an Android live wallpaper maybe because only few wants to create a tutorial for it. So I decided to create my own from scratch and with little knowledge on how to create live wallpaper. Maybe if I became expert on this I could create a tutorial about live wallpaper someday, for all beginners out there. Hmm So my question, Do I have to study open gl to create a very live wallpaper in android? For starters should I jump to that or study the drawings in android first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many tutorials on Live WallPapers . Here i post some of them.

http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/256-live-wallpaper-example

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android/

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers